# How do I import text from a file into an array?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have an array: `var arr = [[]]`, and I have a text file which contains the array like this:

```
[["R", "T", "A", "N", "T", "D", "G", "P", "E", "P"],
["O", "W", "N", "A", "U", "D", "N", "Z", "E", "Y"]]
```

How would I put the array from the text file into the `var arr = [[]]` I just created?
I tried this, but it just says "String from content can not be put into type [[Any]]"

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example", ofType: "txt") {
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
        arr = contents
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
    }
} else {
    // example.txt not found!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`JSONDecoder`** to decode the `String` `data` in file,

```
var arr = [[String]]()

if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example", ofType: "txt") {
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
        if let data = contents.data(using: .utf8) {
            arr = try JSONDecoder().decode([[String]].self, from: data)
            print(arr)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
} else {
    print("File not found")
}
```

Comment: I've got no errors, but it always puts a "File not found".

Comment: Check if your file is named `example.txt` and is added in your project.

Comment: There is some issue with the file getting added to your project. Check if its target is set in the attributes inspector. The code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
 let data = contents.data(using: .utf8)!
 let array = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: 
      .allowFragments) as? [[String]]
```

Comment: Now it shows "Cannot assign value of type '[[String]]?' to type '[[String]].Type'".